# How to calculate countdown timer with a single timezone for all users in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating an auction page.As of now the code works fine and Its showing a countdown timer which only calculates the difference according to the local timezone but not all users will have the same timezone. So I tried `.toUtc` but it still calculates from the device local timezone.

Im using this package to calculate and display timer.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_countdown_timer

All these codes are from the package.

```
_diffTime(Duration duration) {
    value = max(value - duration.inMilliseconds, 0);
    _lastTimestamp = DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecond;
    if (value <= 0) {
      stop();
      onEnd?.call();
      return;
    }
  }
```

This is the input  for the timer.

```
CountdownTimer(
            endTime: DateTime(2020, 10, 22, 12, 48, 00).toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.pink),
          )
```

Comment: Looking at this code you are not using _lastTimestamp anywhere in your code

Comment: That's a part of a other codes in the file. Don't worry about that. The timer works fine . I just want the timer to run according to a single timezone rather than the device time

Comment: What is `CountdownTimer`?  Is that your own class?  If it's from a third-party package, which package?  Why does `_diffTime` compute a difference of `Duration`s instead of a difference of `DateTime` objects?  Where is `_diffTime` used?  You basically have not given readers nearly enough information to figure out where your problem is.

Comment: @jamesdlin . I edited my quesiton and this is the package I'm using [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_countdown_timer)

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  If your expectation is that the hard-coded `DateTime(2020, 10, 22, 12, 48, 00)` object should represent the same moment in time for all users, then you should be using `DateTime.utc` to construct a UTC time instead of a local one.

Comment: No, `DateTime.utc(...)` constructs a `DateTime` object from values representing a UTC time.  `DateTime(...).toUtc()` constructs an object from values representing a local time and converts it to UTC.  They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CountdownTimer` object hard-codes the end time to be `DateTime(2020, 10, 22, 12, 48, 00).toUtc()`.  This creates a `DateTime` object representing October 22, 2020 12:48:00 PM in your *local time* and then returns the corresponding UTC time.  Your hard-coded end-time therefore would represent different points in time when your code is run on systems using different local time zones.

If you instead want October 22, 2020 12:48:00 PM as a UTC time so that it represents the same moment in time regardless of the system's local time zone, then you should construct it as `DateTime.utc(2020, 10, 22, 12, 48, 00)`.  [`DateTime.utc(...)`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.utc.html) and [`DateTime(...).toUtc(...)`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/toUtc.html) are not the same thing.

Also, even though your `_diffTime` function is completely irrelevant to your question, I'll point out that:

```dart
    _lastTimestamp = DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecond;
```

doesn't do what you probably intend. [`DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecond`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/millisecond.html) returns the millisecond *component* of the current `DateTime`.  You likely instead intended to use [`DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/millisecondsSinceEpoch.html).  Note that `.toUtc()` is unnecessary.